# Tag for a single algebraic equation?

Tags: discussion, tagging

This may seem like a silly question but I can't seem to find something to tag a question asking a solution for an [algebraic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_equation). There is a [systems-of-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systems-of-equations) tag, but its description seems to strongly imply that it should only be used for... ahem... a system with more than one equation.

Comment: Some of the tags ([tag:algebra-precalculus]), ([tag:polynomials]), ([tag:roots]),
([tag:quadratics]), ([tag:cubic-equations]) might be suitable for such question. (Notice that
the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/polynomials/info) for (polynomials)
specifically mentions *solving for roots*.)

Comment: Ok, but not all algebraic equations involve polynomials. The [most recent example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120009/how-to-solve-%D1%81urrent-exponential-equatation) tagged "systems-of-equations" involves only exponentials (in a singe equation). N.B.: I see the commonly accepted def for "algebraic equation" involves only polynomials. What should we even call the other "algebraic" ones that aren't differential?

Comment: I see "zeropoints" is a tag-synonym for "roots". I suppose one could add a mention of "roots" in the description of a "systems-of-equations", along the lines of "For a single equation (roots of a function)" use the tag "roots".

Comment: I see that Wikipedia is doing it the other way around, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Root_of_a_function redirects to "Zero of a function".

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Just call them "equations" :)

Comment: There would really be no good reason to have a tag for single algebraic equations.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, perhaps you're looking for [tag:transcendental-equations]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are already a lot of tags for equations, including [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus), [polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polynomials), [roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roots), [quadratics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratics), [cubic-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cubic-equations).

Additionally, if none of these apply, you can consider tagging with [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis), [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis), or [diophantine-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diophantine-equations) according to the domain in which you seek solutions. I think this would allow for almost all questions to have at least one applicable tag, which is probably the most important goal of your suggestion. Sure, these won't be the most descriptive tag, but a prospective [algebraic-equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-equation) wouldn't carry a lot of information either.

Basically, I cannot imagine why someone would be specifically (un)interested in single equations (whereas [systems-of-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systems-of-equations) has ties with e.g. linear algebra). This strongly reduces the merits of having the tag, to the point where I don't see a virtue in having it.

Comment: And [tag:transcendental-equations] in addition to those, as Antonio Vargas pointed out. Thanks for writing a detailed answer pointing out almost all the [better] alternatives.